# What is the point of using /api/v1/(whatever route here) in express?

Tags: express, server, web-development-server

Ive been making API's for about a year now and I was taught to use http://IPAddress:Port/api/v1 all the time when building an API with express.js. Is there a specific reason I would want to do that? Is this just denoting that the API is in development? Ive recently changed my API to not run on port 3000 so that I am able to just say http://IPAddress.com/ instead of http://IPAddress.com:3000/api/v1 and it works just fine the new way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One main reason for versioning an API is because it may be that an API can be improved upon but doing so might lead to breaking changes (for example, it might not work for applications that are consuming the API because an endpoint has been modified).

So, the solution to this is to allow consumers of the current API (v1) to keep using it until they want to switch, and release an updated version (v2) for new consumers.

Here's some more info on it: https://restfulapi.net/versioning/

Comment: Thank you. I guess I didn't think of this since I've mainly only created and finished API's, havent really updated since. Perfect answer by the way